# Utilizando variável com o comando sed

Tags: bash, shell

Tenho a seguinte ocorrência:

```
DirUpload=/var/log
find $DirUpload | sed 's/$DirUpload//g'
```

A pergunta é, como utilizar variável junto com o sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme a resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151954/how-to-use-variables-in-a-command-in-sed):

```
DirUpload=/var/log
find $DirUpload | sed "s|$DirUpload\/||g"
```

- Use aspas duplas para expandir as variáveis
- Use um separador diferente de `/` (no exemplo: `|`)

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar aspas duplas ao invés de simples:

```
  DirUpload=/var/log
  find $DirUpload | sed "s/$DirUpload//g"
```

Comment: Ao fazer dessa forma ai dá o seguinte retorno: (sed: -e expressão #1, char 9: unknown option to `s')

Comment: O que você está querendo substituir nos arquivos que ele encontrar ?